# How do I get toolbars on UISplitView detail & root views?

Tags: toolbar, ipad

I'm porting my iPhone app to iPad.  I have a bunch of detail views that derive from UIViewController and implement UITableViewDelegate.  (Basically TableViews but not derived as such).  The old app used TabBar, but now I'd like to use SplitView with toolbars on the Detail and Master views.  How do I enable a toolbar on my UIViewController inside a UISplitViewController?  I'm not using Interface Builder here, just code.

```
@interface  HeadlineViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

UITableView *tableView;
NSMutableArray *bullIds;

UIActivityIndicatorView *prog;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is how to do it.  Turn the Detail view into an actual UINavigationController.

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/